# Why is my container not spreading to cover this one page?

Tags: html, width, screen, containers

My container is the same across all the pages on my site, but on this one page nothing lines up and I'm not sure why. I have included a screen shot of what I mean.

[image]

Any ideas as to what the issue may be? The code is below:

```
<body>
    <div class="conatiner">
        <div class="logonav">
            <img class="titles" src="images/gold-leaf_contactus.png">
            <div class="nav">
                <a href="index.html">Home</a>
                <a href="soundview-gallery.html">Gallery</a>
                <a href="grandballroom.html">Grand Ballroom</a>
                <a href="reviews.html">Reviews</a>
                <a href="contact-soundview.html">Contact &#38; Directions</a>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="condescbox">
            <div id="directions">
                <h3>DIRECTIONS TO SOUNDVIEW</h3>
                <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d3015.2619042248334!2d-73.57730779999997!3d40.91000299999998!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x89c29b4162df26ab%3A0xcfd53292f4e9c04f!2s45+Bayville+Ave%2C+Bayville%2C+NY+11709!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sus!4v1442592682653" width="600" height="450" frameborder="0" style="border:0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
                <p id="conp">
                    FROM WEST &#40;NY CITY&#41;&#58; 
                    Take LIE Exit 41N for 106/107 North towards Oyster Bay. Merge onto 106/107 and follow 106 all the way to Oyster Bay. Turn left onto Lexington Ave, then left on W Main Street. Follow W Main Street along the shore and across the bridge. W Main St becomes W Shore Road, which becomes Ludlam Ave. Turn left onto Bayville Ave. Bridgette's Bayville Luncheonette is on the corner. 45 Bayville Avenue will be on the right in about half a mile.
                </p>

                <p id="conp">
                    FROM THE EAST&#58; Take the LIE to Exit 41N or Northern State Pkwy Exit 35N towards 106/107. Continue into NY-106. Turn left onto Lexington Ave, then turn left onto W Main St. W Main St. becomes W Shore Rd. Bear right onto W Shore Rd, which becomes Ludlam Ave. Turn left onto Bayville Ave. Bridgette's Bayville Luncheonette is on the corner. Continue for half a mile. 45 Bayville Avenue is on the right.
                </p>

                <p id="conp">
                    FROM THE SOUTH&#58; Take any highway North to the LIE or Northern State Pkwy. Take LIE exit 41N or Northern State exit 35N. Continue onto NY-106. Turn left onto Lexington Ave, then turn left on W Main St. W Main St. becomes W Shore Rd. Bear right onto W Shore Rd, which becomes Ludlam Ave. Turn left onto Bayville Ave. Bridgette's Bayville Luncheonette is on the corner. Continue for half a mile. 45 Bayville Avenue is on the right.
                </p>
            </div>

            <p id="fillout">Fill out the form below to schedule an appointment and get an event quote.</p>

            <iframe id="JotFormIFrame" onload="window.parent.scrollTo(0,0)" allowtransparency="true" src="https://form.jotform.com/52926673733161" frameborder="0" style="width:100%; height:1531px; border:none;" scrolling="no"></iframe>
            <script type="text/javascript">
                window.handleIFrameMessage = function(e) {
                    var args = e.data.split(":");
                    var iframe = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame");

                    if (!iframe) return;

                    switch (args[0]) {
                        case "scrollIntoView":
                            iframe.scrollIntoView();
                            break;
                        case "setHeight":
                            iframe.style.height = args[1] + "px";
                            break;
                        case "collapseErrorPage":
                            if (iframe.clientHeight > window.innerHeight) {
                                iframe.style.height = window.innerHeight + "px";
                            }
                            break;
                        case "reloadPage":
                            window.location.reload();
                            break;
                    }

                    var isJotForm = (e.origin.indexOf("jotform") > -1) ? true : false;

                    if(isJotForm && "contentWindow" in iframe && "postMessage" in iframe.contentWindow) {
                        var urls = {"docurl":encodeURIComponent(document.URL),"referrer":encodeURIComponent(document.referrer)};

                        iframe.contentWindow.postMessage(JSON.stringify({"type":"urls","value":urls}), "*");
                    }
                };

                if (window.addEventListener) {
                    window.addEventListener("message", handleIFrameMessage, false);
                } else if (window.attachEvent) {
                    window.attachEvent("onmessage", handleIFrameMessage);
                }

                if(window.location.href && window.location.href.indexOf("?") > -1) {
                    var ifr = document.getElementById("JotFormIFrame");
                    var get = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.indexOf("?") + 1);

                    if(ifr && get.length > 0) {
                        var src = ifr.src; src = src.indexOf("?") > -1 ? src + "&" + get : src + "?" + get; ifr.src = src;
                    }
                }
            </script>
         </div>

         <div class="imgwrapper">
            <img src="images/contactsoundviewNEW.png">  
         </div>  
    </div>  
    <footer class="footer">  
        <p>Long Island | Nassau County | Bayville | Manhasset | Brookville | Great Neck &copy;Soundview Caterers 2016  | Design by Katya Temidis</p>
    </footer>
</body>
```

CSS:

```
.contacthtml {
    background-color: #e6d7c1; 
    background-size: cover;
}  

.container {
    max-width: 1600px;
    margin: auto;
}
```

Thanks,
Katya

Comment: May be your code can get us some idea

Comment: Please post your code or a fiddle of it.